# Binding xml data from Excel Workbook to Main Page TextBlock in Silverlight 5

Tags: xml, data-binding, textbox, silverlight-5.0

So I've been googling all over on webpages and in e-books.

I have a DatePicker and I would like to bind that to search every xml row for the corresponding date and display the two fields, Place and Special, within the row into preset TextBoxes on the MainPage.

Any suggestions?

MainPage.xaml

```
  <UserControl
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk"
    x:Class="SilverlightApplication6.MainPage"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="33*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="367*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="106.164,25,0,0"
            VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Grid.Column="1">
            <sdk:DatePicker Height="23" Width="120"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,75,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap"
         Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,96,0,0"
         TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,157,0,0"
         TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,178,313,0"
         TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

    </Grid>
  </UserControl>
```

Menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Menu xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Row>
        <Place>Club Del Monte Lunch Specials</Place>
        <Start_Date>41428</Start_Date>
        <Special>CAF DEL MONTEBBQ Pork RibswithBeans and ColeslawEL PRADO DINING
             ROOMMain Entre Choices: Beef EnchiladasPork EnchiladasSide Choices:
             Spanish RiceOrRefried BeansandSauted Yellow Squash and ZucchiniSoup of
             the Day:Chicken and Rice Caldo     Subject to Availability</Special>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Place>TRIDENT DINNER SPECIAL: Seafood Cioppino </Place>
        <Start_Date>41428</Start_Date>
        <Special>With Clams, Mussels, Salmon, Scallops, Crab, Fish and Shrimp.
             Served with Garlic Bread    $16.00Appetizer:Combination with 3 Wings, 3
             Poppers, 3 Chicken Tenders     $8.75</Special>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Place>Club Del Monte Lunch Specials</Place>
        <Start_Date>41429</Start_Date>
        <Special>CAF DEL MONTETri Tip SandwichwithColeslawEL PRADO DINING ROOMMain
             Entre Choices: Grilled Chicken Breast with Roasted Pepper Cream SauceMeat
             LoafSide Choices:Garlic Mashed PotatoesOrStuffingandSteamed Broccoli and
             CauliflowerSoup of the Day:Yellow Lentil with Chicken      Subject to
             Availability</Special>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Place>TRIDENT ROOM DINNER SPECIAL: Prime Rib</Place>
        <Start_Date>41429</Start_Date>
        <Special>Served with Baked Potato, AuJus and Steamed Vegetables $17.00
             Appetizer:  Shrimp Cocktail    $6.50</Special>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Place>Club Del Monte Lunch Specials</Place>
        <Start_Date>41430</Start_Date>
        <Special>CAF DEL MONTEChicken CurryoverRiceEL PRADO DINING ROOMMain Entre
             Choices: Grilled Red Snapper with Cucumber RelishSpaghetti with Meat
             SauceSide Choices:Roasted Red and Yukon PotatoesandSauted Medley of
             VegetablesSoup of the Day:Beef with Vegetables     Subject to
             Availability</Special>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Place>Club Del Monte Lunch Specials</Place>
        <Start_Date>41431</Start_Date>
        <Special>CAF DEL MONTEPersonalCombination PizzaEL PRADO DINING ROOMMain
             Entre Choices: Roasted Pork Loin with Pineapple Ginger SauceSweet and
             Sour ChickenSide Choices:Fried RiceandEgg RollsSoup of the Day:Rice with
             Vegetables and Ham     Subject to Availability</Special>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Place>Trident Room Dinner Special</Place>
        <Start_Date>41431</Start_Date>
        <Special>Seafood Linguini with Clams and Mussels.  Served with Garlic
             Bread  $14.50</Special>
    </Row>
</Menu>
```